# Filter based on header name instead of column position google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I am having pretty much same situation as this [VBA, Advanced Filter Based on Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057672/vba-advanced-filter-based-on-header) but in googlesheets.

I want filter columns based on header instead of column index as they are not always in same columns.   (Few Header names : Candidate ID, Name, Resume)

this piece of code filters based on column position

```
` var cidFilter = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextStartsWith("CID").build();   
  var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter();
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(17,cidFilter);`
```

i want it to filter based on header ***(Candidate ID)*** instead of position `(17,cidFilter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can find the column containing the header with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Sample:

```
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1:G1").getValues()[0]; // adjust accordingly to your header range
  var column=headers.indexOf("Candidate ID")+1;
  if(column >0){
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(column,cidFilter);
  }
```

### UPDATE:

If you want to apply two filter criteria, do the following:

```
  var column=headers.indexOf("Candidate ID")+1;
  var column2=headers.indexOf("Are you currently under a non-solicit agreement ?")+1;
  if(column > 0){
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(column,cidFilter);
  }
  if(column2 > 0){
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(column2,nonSolicit);
  }
```

Comment: Works great! small query (sorry)  if i want to add additional header to it, should i put whole code again you have given? asking this because i have to filter 4 columns (Candidate ID, Name, Resume & URL)

Comment: In my sample the headers are in the range `"A1:G1"` - you can adapt the range to your needs. And the position of each header can be queried with `headers.indexOf("NAME OF HEADER")+1;`

Comment: I tried but its considering only one column for filtering i have put what i edited in the question please see what went wrong and what need to be done

Comment: I see. For each header you need to create a new variable for the respective column - see my updated answer.

Comment: Worked great thanks! Does this method works for copy paste also? asking this as now its copying wrong data... **i want to copy "Candidate ID" column and paste it in next column no matter where "Candidate ID" column is present**

Comment: Could you please provide code to copy Candidate ID column to next column, i am unable to accomplish that

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your request correctly. In agreement with the Stackoverflow guidelines, the correct procedure would be to accept the answer that was helpful to solve your initial question and - if you have a new question - create a new post explaining the new issue in detail.